# How to read python subprocess stdout without communicate

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, shell

I have a python 3 script that accepts input from the user, this input is piped into a subprocess, where a shell has been spawned. Originally I was going to put this code together with a socket, to be able to make my own non-serious remote administration tool, however this proves too hard for my level currently. Code:

```
import subprocess

p1 = subprocess.Popen(["/bin/sh"], stderr = subprocess.PIPE, stdin = subprocess.PIPE, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, encoding = "utf-8")

command = input("Command: ")

p1.stdin.write(command)

p1.stdout.read()
```

> Problem: Nothing gets printed out. I have searched endless hours
>   online for a reason, over multiple days, but all of them don't seem to
>   work, and/or advise using communicate() which is something I do not
>   want to do. When thinking ahead if I am able to implement this with a
>   socket, I can't have the process closing after each command. I have
>   also tried flushes everywhere, before write, inbetween the read, after
>   the read, pretty much everywhere you can think of. It should be simple
>   enough, without me having to look deep into the io module or the rules
>   of buffering (too late now). I have been struggling with this for days
>   on end.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! When you post blocks of code, please add four spaces at the start of each line to make it display as a code snippet. For more information on formatting posts, read the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of issues, I will try to draw the path, I hope I am not misleading you.

First of all, disclaimer: executing user input is inherently unsafe. If that's not an issue, let's keep on your problem.

I would start by doing

```
p1 = subprocess.Popen(["/bin/sh"], stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True, bufsize=1)
```

Having a line-buffered PIPE is a good idea, in this scenario.

Then, remember that you have to press enter after the command, so:

```
command = input("Command: ") + "\n"
```

The write is correct,

```
p1.stdin.write(command)
```

But the, the read is VERY dangerous and you will trivially become deadlocked. Because the `stdout` is open (without an EOF or anything like that) you should read conservatively, and still, you will have problems on that.

A first idea would be to read lines:

```
p1.stdout.readline()
```

But, if you don't know how many lines you can read... then that's a problem. In fact, that specific problem [has already been asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375427/non-blocking-read-on-a-subprocess-pipe-in-python).

If you want to experiment, just open an interactive python interpreter, send a `"ls\n"` command and perform `readline()`. It will work, until you read the last line, and then... it will wait forever. That is bad behaviour. So you will need to solve that.